# Using Cassandra online - no installation

Tags: cassandra

Is there a simple way to use and explain Cassandra without having to install it.
I mean a solution that with be ready to exploit over the cloud or whatever (like the ready to use compiler for sql in W3schools for example)

Comment: You could always do a free account on Astra DB (DataStax’s Cassandra as a Service).  https://auth.cloud.datastax.com/auth/realms/CloudUsers/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=auth-proxy&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgatekeeper.auth.cloud.datastax.com%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&state=WZ0D%2BRFKkZwUXBcdTiTYDLon168%3D

Comment: Full disclosure; I do work for DataStax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf)** is a Cassandra-as-a-service offering which has a free tier you could use exactly for that purpose.

You can launch a Cassandra cluster on the cloud in literally just 5 clicks and there's no credit card required to create an account. Cheers!

Comment: thanks so much, I'll try it out and get back if any problem

Comment: @b.m, you could also watch [these YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm-EPIkBI3YqtWR5w9uZEss50GjpWI5hG) to get started on the same and/or refer to the [product documentation](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm-EPIkBI3YqtWR5w9uZEss50GjpWI5hG).